# ARM assembly variable declaration

Tags: variables, assembly, arm, cortex-a8

Hi I have a question about the order of declaration variables.
Little example.
If in declaration i write:

```
    .data
    .align  0
res:    .long 0
num:    .long   7
var2:   .short  30
```

the program works, but if I write this:

```
    .data
    .align  0
    res:    .long 0
    var2:   .short  30
    num:    .long   7
```

the program don't work:
for example I can't do a simple

```
ldr     r5, =num
ldr     r5, [r5]
```

with the second configuration. the error is: no source available for "0x20010"

I'm using eclipse on a processor am335x
Thx

Comment: That looks like an alignment issue, but the error message is strange.

Comment: what is an alignment issue? I don't understand very well the meaning of .aling

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926386/what-is-non-aligned-access-arm-keil

Comment: That looks more like a message from a debugger stopping due to a breakpoint or signal and trying to show the source line of the instruction it's stopped at, rather than whatever error actually caused it to stop in the first place.

Comment: SOLVED, if some one is interested I explain here:
Is a problem of alignment, because I tough that one time you write the directive .aligne this is for all the next command, but is not like that. So if I write .aligne 4 before num it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED, if some one is interested I explain here: It's a problem of alignment, because I tough that once you write the directive .aligne this is for all the next commands, but is not like that. So if I write .aligne 4 before num it works.